# How to add test folders to an older Android Studio Project

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, android-studio

I'm having some problems adding the project structure for testing, to an older Android project in Android Studio.

When you create a new project in Android Studio, you get the directories for testing created from start.

```
src/test/java - for unit testing 
src/androidTest/java - for Android/UI testing.
```

But our project didn't have those, since it's an older project we have migrated from Eclipse.

I have succesfully added the directory (test) and java folder (test/java) for unit testing to our project, where the java directory is recognized as a java directory, so I can add new packages and java files.

When I look at the packages in the Android Project view, they're listed as:

```
com.ourcompany.ourapp
com.ourcompany.ourapp (test) - And here I can see my testclasses.
```

All good so far.

But I cannot seem add the structure for androidTest.

If I add the directory androidTest and a javafolder called java under it, the java folder is marked as green, and I can add classes and packages. But the testpackage is not marked as a test.

I get this result in the android project view.

```
com.ourcompany.ourapp
com.ourcompany.ourapp - And here is the testclass, MainActivityTest.java
com.ourcompany.ourapp (test)
```

When I added the androidTest/java folder, this line appeared in the build.gradle file:

```
android { sourceSets { main { java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/androidTest/java/'] } } }
```

If I remove that line, then the androidTest/java folder is no longer recognized as a javafolder, and I cannot add classes/packages there anymore. And in the Android Project View, the MainActivityTest class is no longer visible at all.

What am I missing, when it comes to adding the androidTest folders, for it to be recognized as a test folder structure?

Is there something I need to add to the gradles file?

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ourcompany.ourapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds true
        abortOnError false
    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.1'
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.+"
}

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

First of all, create two directory under the src folder.

Names are;

1) androidTest

2) test

Then add java folders under these directories.

Should be like this "androidTest > java" and "test > java".

After that, open any source file in the current project. Press Alt + Enter than click "Create Test" section. Choose your test directory what do you want and write your tests.

Answer (score 1):

For UnitTest

```
sourceSets {
    test.root 'test'
    test.java.srcDirs 'test/java'
}
```

for Android Instrumentation Test

```
sourceSets {`enter code here`
    androidTest.root 'src/tests/androidTest'
    androidTest.java.srcDirs 'src/tests/androidTest/java'
}
```